# R doParallel: Function cannot find function even though it appears in the environment

Tags: r, doparallel

**TLDR problem: A function that works in normal circumstances does not work when running in parallel using the doParallel package because it cannot find a function (even though I am exporting the needed function)**

I have the following problem with respect to the `doParallel` package (parallelized for loops) and the `GPArotation` package (matrix rotation algorithm)

Basically, I can define a matrix and a criterion that I want to optimize, and then `GPForth` function will rotate that matrix to optimize the criterion.

**EXAMPLE (no parallel programming, works)**

```
# load packages 
library(GPArotation) 
library(doParallel)

# Define test  matrix
B <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2) # generate 2x2 test metrix

# specify functions to be called by GPForth
absmin.criteria <- function(L) {
  sum(abs(L))
}

vgQ.absmin <- function (L) {
  list(Gq = sign(L), 
       f = absmin.criteria(L), 
       Method = "absmin")
}

# perform optimization
GPForth(B, method = "absmin")

#WORKS!
```

**EXAMPLE (with parallel programming, does NOT work)**

```
# Set up parallelization
cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1) #not to overload computer
registerDoParallel(cl)

results <- foreach(m=1:2, .combine = rbind, .export = c('GPForth', 'absmin.criteria', 'vgQ.absmin')) %dopar% {
           GPForth(B, method = 'absmin')
    }
stopCluster(cl)

#ERROR in {: task 1 failed - "could not find function "vgQ.absmin""
```

I do not understand why GPForth cannot find `vgQ.absmin`, since I am feeding it directly via the '.export' argument. Note: just running `exists('vgQ.absmin')` within the loop returns TRUE. But for some reason GPForth cannot find it.

I do not understand enought about parallelization in R to know how this can happen. Any ideas?